# How to make Drupal redirect to pages after user registration

Tags: php, drupal

I have a Drupal website and I want to show different welcome pages, depending on what my users enter as profile fields. I can't use the global $user variable, because users are not automatically logged in (They have to very their email address before they can log in).

Where can I add code to set the redirect?
I've tried with $form['#redirect'] and $form_state['redirect'] in the form validator, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [logintobogan](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--logintoboggan--logintoboggan.module/6) for inspiration:

```
#implementation of hook_user
mymodule_user($op) { 
  if ($op == 'login') {
    $_REQUEST['destination'] = '/user/will/be/redirected/here'
  }
}
```

The important part is to make sure, that by the time the final `drupal_goto()` is called in user.module, you have set your `$_REQUEST['destination']`.

A few things to note:

1. Logintoboggan has a lot of code to deal with all sorts of edge-cases, such as redirecting out/to https. You can ignore these, if your case is simple.
2. Your module must be called after user.module and probably after other modules implementing hook_user, for they might change this **global** too. Very ugly, but the way this works in Drupal.
3. Do not -ever- issue `drupal_goto()` in any hook. Especially not hook_user, or hook_form_alter. drupal_goto will prohibit other hooks from being called; breaking functionality at the least, but often corrupting your database.
4. Do not issue `drupal_goto()` in form_alter callbacks such as "_submit", this might break many other modules and might even corrupt your database.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Berke's answer, but it seems like you just want this to be a one time thing.  For that, you can check for the $account->access property to check their last login.  If it is 0, then they are logging in for the first time.

This should work fine for email or no email validation.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_user().
 */
function mymodule_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'login':
      // execute this if they have never accessed the site before
      if ($account->access == 0) {
        // run conditional logic based on profile fields
        // to set destination here
        $_REQUEST['destination'] = 'path/to/welcome-page';
      }
      break;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Adding a switch/case for one case is silly. Consider replacing that with an `if(($op == 'login') && ($account->access == 0)) {`. Saves many brains from exploding.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [Login Destionation module](http://drupal.org/node/69051) or you can use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module [redirect action](http://drupal.org/node/298506) which is maybe to robust for your purpose.

Just in case you don't want to write your own custom module :-)

Comment: I would not suggest you make your decision based on "wanting to write your module". Rules and modules such as logintoboggan, login-destination, provide some basic configurable redirection-logic, but nothing fancy. If you need actual business-logic, nothing beats a few lines of PHP. Ask yourself: do I need business-logic such as "if user has payed, he goes to Foo"? Then just create a module for that.

Comment: i tried to use this module. it didn't work for me. so frustrated in general with third party modules. almost always revert to my own which are usually simpler